# How do I differentiate this?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am given $u=\frac{x+y}{\sqrt 2}$ and $v=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2}$, how would I find $\frac{d^2}{du^2},\frac{d^2}{dv^2}$?

I rearranged $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, and I get $x = \frac{u + v}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y = \frac{u - v}{\sqrt{2}}$. But how do I find $\frac{d^2}{du^2}$ and $\frac{d^2}{dv^2}$?

Comment: Thanks, so is the answer for both, $0$?

Comment: What are you differentiating in this expression: $\frac{d^2}{dv^2}$?

Comment: @Emmad: It doesnt state anything in the problem, although you can take a look at the original question below (note the $v$ changes to $w$ in the original question).
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99608/change-of-variables-of-pde

Comment: sorry this is not too advanced for me :)

Comment: haha no problem, its ok.

Answer (score 3):

if $f$ is a function of $x,y$ then
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\Big)
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Big(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}
+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\Big)

+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\Big(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\Big)
$$
$$
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial u^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\Big(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\Big)^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\Big(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\Big)^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
$$
note
$$x=(u+v)\sqrt{2}, y=(u-v)\sqrt{2},\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\sqrt{2}$$
so the above simplifies to
$$
4\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}+2\Big(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\Big)
$$
you can do the same thing with respect to $v$ (i assumed equality of mixed partials above)

Comment: Thanks, Im just wondering, how did you get $x=(u+v)\sqrt{2}$ and $y=(u-v)\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply $\partial_u$ you take the directional  derivative with respect to the vector $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,1)$, so $\partial u =\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(\partial x+\partial y)$. Now take the directional  derivative with respect to the vector $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}(1,1)$ of $\partial u$. We get $\partial^2_u=\frac 12(\partial^2_x+\partial_x\partial_y+\partial_y\partial_x+\partial_y^2)$. Now, do the same for $\partial_v$ and $\partial_v^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what you did, but for $\partial^2u=\frac 12(\partial^2_x+\partial_x\partial y+\partial_y\partial_x+\partial_y^2)$, what exactly do I differentiate? What would $\partial^2_x$ be for example?

Comment: $\partial_x^2$ apply to a function $f$ is only the the two times derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Thanks, but what would the $f$ be? $\frac{x+y}{\sqrt 2}$?

Comment: Not necessary, here $f$ is only a function on which you apply the operator $\partial_u$.

Comment: Thanks, Im sorry but im really stuck on this question. How would I find $\partial^2_x,\partial_x\partial_y,\partial_y\partial_x,\partial_y^2$ etc.? As in, what do I differentiate when I am trying to find $\partial_x^2$?

Comment: $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ just give the partial derivative of a function, with respect to the first and the second variable. What you wanted is how to expressed $\partial_u^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u^2}$ in terms of $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$.